# What does (Resolving Host) means?

Tags: vb6, winsock

I'm sorry if this is not a programmatic issue, i also may get many down votes for it, but i really need to know in details, what does (Resolving Host) means ?!

I'm trying to configure a connection to a web server hosting a friend's web site, and i'm developing a vb6.0 app. using WinSock.OCX tool, and one of its states is (Resolving Host) so i need to know what does it mean to be able to provide some code for it.

Comment: Most probably it's been handed a URL that includes a human-readable domain name; it's looking up the domain name's IP address.

Comment: What if i provided an IP address?! would i still get the message (Resolving Host) ?!
BTW @Steve Rindsberg thanx for commenting

Comment: Please choose tags appropriate to your question (this isn't `vba`, and `mean` is just... well, meaningless :)). Also, formatting your entire question in **bold** ruins the whole meaning of formatting in **bold**, which is to add **emphasis** to a specific section of text; if you apply it to everything, there's absolutely no added emphasis to **anything**. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to handle that state. This is just the phase when WinSock.ocx is converting a DNS name (let's say *www.dilbert.com*) to the corresponding IP (*184.106.169.31*). This is handled automatically by WinSock, so you just have to wait.

WinSock might give you errors during this phase, because it could be that

1. the supplied domain name is/was no longer valid
2. the supplied domain name is invalid (*92$!#d.com*, for example)
3. the DNS server is not available (no network connection, for example)